# Logentries fails when Django management command run as cron job in Dotcloud

Tags: django, cron, dotcloud, logentries

I have a Django application running on [Dotcloud](http://dotcloud.com/). I have tried to add [Logentries](http://logentries.com/) logging which works in normal usage for my site, but causes my cron jobs to fail with this error -
    `Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/dotcloud/current/my_project/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/home/dotcloud/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/home/dotcloud/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/home/dotcloud/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
        commands = get_commands()
      File "/home/dotcloud/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
        apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
      File "/home/dotcloud/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
        self._setup(name)
      File "/home/dotcloud/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 50, in _setup
        self._configure_logging()
      File "/home/dotcloud/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 80, in _configure_logging
        logging_config_func(self.LOGGING)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 777, in dictConfig
        dictConfigClass(config).configure()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 575, in configure
        '%r: %s' % (name, e))
    ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'logentries_handler': expected string or buffer`

This is one of the scripts being run from cron -

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Loading definitions - check /var/log/supervisor/availsserver.log for results"
. /etc/profile
/home/dotcloud/env/bin/python /home/dotcloud/current/my_project/manage.py load_definitions
```

These are my settings for Logentries -
    `'logentries_handler': {
        'token': os.getenv("LOGENTRIES_TOKEN"),
        'class': 'logentries.LogentriesHandler'
        }
    ....
    'logentries': {
       'handlers': ['logentries_handler'],
       'level': 'INFO',
       },`

The LOGENTRIES_TOKEN is there when I do `dotcloud env list`.

**This is a summary of the symptoms -**
- Logentries logging works from the site in normal usage.
- If I manually run the script - `dotcloud run www ~/current/scripts/load_definitions.sh` it works.
- If I remove the Logentries settings from my `settings.py` the cron jobs work.
- The cron jobs fail if Logentries entries are in my `settings.py`

I have spent hours trying to find a solution. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this.
This is the crontab before -
`0 13 * * * /home/dotcloud/current/scripts/load_definitions.sh 2>&1 | mail -s "Load definitions result" myemail@example.com.au`
which didn't work.
This is how it is now -
`0 13 * * * /bin/bash -l -c '/home/dotcloud/current/scripts/load_definitions.sh' 2>&1 | mail -s "Load definitions result" myemail@example.com.au`
which works. Adding `/bin/bash -l -c` fixed it. Perhaps someone can tell me why it didn't work the way it was?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading the value directly from `~/environment.json` or `~/environment.yml`, instead of from the exported shell environment?